# using xml/xslt to display data into 2 columns

Tags: xml, xslt, multiple-columns

xml data:
Brennan withdrew from consideration for the spy agency's top job in 2008 amid questions about his connection to harsh interrogation techniques used during the George W. Bush administration. He is certain to face questions about the issue again from Democrats while Republicans press him on leaks of classified information in the Obama administration.

expected result:
content show in 2 columns like http://jackbu.host22.com/t.jpg

please find my comments below. I've attached the xml/xsl file links there.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but could you be more specific about what you want the result to be?  Is the number of characters per row a certain value? Or does it need to be adjusted so all the rows are the same width and the number of rows per column are equal?  What have you tried so far?  What is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: looks like a sensitive data ;)

Comment: ignore the data, copy paste from google. ;)

Comment: well, basically I need a long paragraph break into 2 columns. The number of letters is not fixed. Actually I've tried substring to show half of the paragraph, but it looks wierd at the bottom of both column. What I want is to fill the left column first with no blanks and put the rest into the right part.

Comment: something like: http://jackbu.host22.com/t2.jpg   Really appreciate if someone can help me with this issue!

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share with us your present attempt?  Is this supposed to be shown in HTML? Something else?  Is it really supposed to split the lines in the middle of words?

Comment: normal view(one column): http://jackbu.host22.com/result.xml ; xml source: http://jackbu.host22.com/jacktest.xml ; xsl source: http://jackbu.host22.com/jacktest.xsl

Comment: my test view(one column): http://jackbu.host22.com/result2.xml ; xml source: http://jackbu.host22.com/jacktest.xml ; xsl source: http://jackbu.host22.com/jacktest2.xsl

Comment: while my expectation is http://jackbu.host22.com/t3.jpg  : fill in the left part first, and the rest goes to the right part

Comment: XSLT is used typically for processing an *XML document*. Please, *edit* the question and provide: 1) The source XML document (small preferred); 2) The exact wanted result; 3) Explanation of any requirements that the transformation must implement.

Comment: I've already put those info in comment. :)